# How do get information from .json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this index.js and it's logging the whole .json file. I want to log the age (21). How do I do that?

```
const fs = require('fs');
 
async function doSomething() {
  const data = fs.readFileSync("./apple.json")
  const data2 = await JSON.parse(data)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data2, null, 2))
}
doSomething()
```

and a side question:
Is there a way to avoid using fs to read files?

```
/*
apple.json

{
   "memberList":[
      {
         "age":"21",
         "name":"Jom"
      }
   ]
}
*/
```

```
/*
Output:
 
{
  "memberList": [
    {
      "age": "21",
      "name": "Jom"
    }
  ]
}
 
*/
```

Comment: Your problem is covered by [introductory tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics). Please learn the very basics of the programming language you are using before resorting to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is quite obvious and this answer will not address it. Regarding your second question, yes. Using commonjs you just have to require the file. Like this:

```js
const data = require('./apple.json');
```

If you are using ES6 modules, then you have to addd a assert statement. Like this:

```
import data from './apple.json' assert {type: 'json'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to access the members of `memberList`?

```
console.log(data2.memberList[0].age);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).